# How to set application name in golang lib/pq postgresql driver?

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm writing a golang application and using the golang postgres driver - https://github.com/lib/pq/

I use a connection string like this

```
'name:pass@host:port/dbname'
```

I try to add aplication_name param in conn string, but this doesn't work

```
'name:pass@host:port/dbname?application_name=myapp'
```

Is it possible to set the application name from golang? (standard way)

Comment: thank apxp! that's work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look to the [documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq) a application_name option is not suuported. Maybe you could use:

> fallback_application_name - An application_name to fall back to if
>   one isn't provided.

```
name:pass@host:port/dbname?fallback_application_name=myapp
```

Comment: But how do you provide one, not as a fallback?

Answer (score 9):

Even though it's not mentioned in the documentation, if you look at the `lib/pq` source code you will find that `application_name` is supported.

This style connection works as desired:

```
connstring := fmt.Sprintf("user='%s' password='%s' dbname='%s' host='%s' application_name='%s'", user, password, dbname, host, application_name)
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connstring)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the application name one of two ways.

```
// Application name as space-separated list of options.
sql.Open("postgres", "user=myuser password=mypass host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb sslmode=disable application_name=myapp")
```

or

```
// Application name as query param.
sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost:5432/mydb?sslmode=disable&application_name=myapp")
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking into this in 2023, if you are using kubernetes or any other cloud native environment the pq library also supports setting the application name via ENV variable by simply specifying:

```
export PGAPPNAME=myapp
```

You can verify this by checking the connection stats:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity ORDER BY application_name;
```

Reference: https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/v1.10.9/conn.go#L2045